# Getting an "Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext" because of FilterSecurityInterceptor in Spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring-boot(1.3.0.RELEASE) application and trying to configure Spring-Security.My POM.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.userservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>UserService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>UserService Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <!--Start dependency for the mongo db -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.156</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-oauth-client-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId> <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId> 
            <version>1.19.1</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>UserService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*tomcat*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My Spring Security Configuration file is :

```
package com.userservice.config.security;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
/**
 * @author Mayank
 * 
 * This class is used for configuring Security related configuration.
 * 
 */
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDecisionVoter;
import org.springframework.security.access.ConfigAttribute;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased;
import org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher;

import com.userservice.dao.DatabaseUserAcountRepository;
import com.userservice.dao.UserAccountRepository;
import com.userservice.filter.CORSFilter;
import com.userservice.repository.policy.PasswordPolicyFactory;
import com.userservice.repository.policy.PasswordPolicyRepository;
import com.userservice.repository.policy.PasswordPolicyRepositoryFileImpl;
import com.userservice.service.StatelessAuthenticationFilter;
import com.userservice.service.TokenAuthenticationService;
import com.userservice.service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserService userService = null;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService = null;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepository = null;

    public SecurityConfig() {
        super(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/userModule/Users/**", "/aa/**", "/rp/**","/userModule/BookShelves/**","/user/shelf/**","/user/notes/**","/http://openlibrary.org/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(
                        new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(
                                tokenAuthenticationService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(
                passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean(name = "authenticationManager")
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserAccountRepository userDetailsService() {
        return new DatabaseUserAcountRepository();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationService("tooManySecrets",
                userDetailsService());
    }

    /*
     * @Bean public TokenHandler tokenHandler() { return new
     * TokenHandler("tooManySecrets", userDetailsService()); }
     */

    /*
     * @Bean public UserSignUpService userSignUpService(){ return new
     * UserSignUpService(); }
     */

    @Bean
    public PasswordPolicyRepositoryFileImpl getPasswordPolicyRepositoryFileImpl() {
        return new PasswordPolicyRepositoryFileImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, PasswordPolicyRepository> getPasswordPolicyFactoryMap() {
        Map<String, PasswordPolicyRepository> map = new HashMap<String, PasswordPolicyRepository>();
        map.put("FilePasswordPolicy", getPasswordPolicyRepositoryFileImpl());
        return map;
    }

    @Bean(name = "passwordPolicyFactory")
    public PasswordPolicyFactory getPasswordPolicyFactory() {
        PasswordPolicyFactory passwordPolicyFactory = new PasswordPolicyFactory();
        passwordPolicyFactory
                .setPasswordPoliciesMap(getPasswordPolicyFactoryMap());
        return passwordPolicyFactory;
    }
}
```

I have Spring rest services behind this security. If I am trying to access the rest service like  POST: http://localhost:8080/userModule/Users, then I am getting following exception because of `FilterSecurityInterceptor.java`, which I haven't configured in my application but it gets magically added in filterchain and throwing below mentioned exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:378) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222) ~[spring-security-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at com.userservice.service.StatelessAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(StatelessAuthenticationFilter.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

As I have configured `/userModule/Users` path as permitAll, so I should be able to access http://localhost:8080/userModule/Users but if I am trying to access the same then I am getting above exception.